# Angular 2: adding *ngIf to SVG throws an error

Tags: angular, svg

This is my SVG of a component (which will be a child another svg):

```
<svg *ngIf="complete" [attr.width]="width" [attr.height]="height" viewBox="0 0 180 100" version="1.1" xml:space="preserve" style="overflow:visible;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;"> ...</svg>
```

I'm getting an error when adding `*ngIf` to a component template with `SVG`:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg'.

`*ngIf` works fine on other parts of the code except for `svg`

`Height` and `Width` attributes binding works fine.

I have checked `ngIf` spelling and model property.
I tested adding  `BrowserModule`, didn't make any difference. 
I have `CommonModule` in `@NgModule` imports.

The component that have the `SVG` is generated by `componentFactory`.

I have Angular 2 Universal (latest version)

Comment: Ensure you have the `CommonModule` added to `imports: [...]` of the module that contains the SVG

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I have mentioned I do have `CommonModule`. If I add `ngIf` to the parent component that does not have `svg` it works!

Answer (score 4):

Setting up dynamic bindings using Angular and SVG requires that you add the attr prefix before the attribute.

Because *ngIf is syntatic sugar for [ngIf], I've gotten around the error message by writing out the ngIf and the ng-template:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="!label.hasCompensation">
        <svg:text text-anchor="middle" [attr.x]="label.x" [attr.y]="label.y">
                {{label.encoder}} |
                <tspan style="fill:red">{{label.compensation}}</tspan>
        </svg:text>
</ng-template>
```

The primary reason for this is that the SVG DOM generally does not expose attributes as properties like the HTML DOM does.

For reference, Tero Parviainen has written an excellent [post on his blog.](https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngClass] instead of *ngIf

in your HTML:

```
<app-trend-chart [data]="trendData"
 [ngClass]="loading.charts.isLoading? 'chartVisible': 'chartNotVisible'">
</app-trend-chart>
```

in your CSS:

```
.chartNotVisible {
    display: none;
}

.chartVisible {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Günter wrote make sure you have the CommonModule available to the module that contains the svg

Here is a working plunkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/XgU2Ns?p=preview

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <rect
    x="20"
    y="20"
    width="100"
    height="100"
  />

  <rect
    *ngIf="showRed"
    x="140"
    y="20"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    style="fill: red;"
  />
</svg>

<button type="button" (click)="showRed = !showRed">Show Red</button>
```