# ngIf not working for SVG icon fill for angular 6

Tags: javascript, svg, angular6, svg-animate, angular-ng-if

Here is my code to implement if condition in SVG tag:

```
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  width="60px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 60 92" enable-background="new 0 0 60 92" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
                   <linearGradient *ngIf="!compareCompanyRevenue" id="progress1019" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
                      <stop id="stop1005" offset="0" stop-color="#e1edf3" />
                      <stop id="stop2005" offset="0" stop-color="#02ABBA" />
                    </linearGradient>
                    <linearGradient *ngIf="compareCompanyRevenue" id="progress1019" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
                      <stop id="stop1005" offset="0" stop-color="#02ABBA" />
                      <stop id="stop2005" offset="0" stop-color="#e1edf3" />
                    </linearGradient> 
    </defs>

//up-arrow
    <path *ngIf="!compareCompanyRevenue" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#progress1019)" stroke="#02ABBA" stroke-miterlimit="10" d=""/>

//down-arrow
    <path *ngIf="compareCompanyRevenue" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#progress1019)" stroke="#02ABBA" stroke-miterlimit="10" d=""/>
    </svg>
```

**test.ts** // for now i'm trying to fill using javascript

```
document.getElementById("stop1005").setAttribute("offset", "0.25");
document.getElementById("stop2005").setAttribute("offset", "0.25");
```

> need to change in "linearGradient" tag (stop-color) depends on condition. But don't
>   impacting my changes.
>
> Up-down arrow is working fine, but I can't fill svg from top or bottom
>   according to my ngIf condition

Comment: have you checked suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030819/angular-2-adding-ngif-to-svg-throws-an-error

Comment: @mtx i can't understand this..

Comment: @mtx i want to change here `stop-color="#02ABBA"`

Comment: import `CommonModule` in module where you use svg, also to use `attr.` prefix with the attribute you want to change.

Comment: @mtx why `CommonModule`?

Comment: it contains [ngIf] directive you want to use

Comment: adding attr. is giving me template error

Comment: @mtx ngif is working for other, issue is in SVG only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179158/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-mtx).